# captureVisibleTab fails on Chrome yet succeeds in Vivaldi

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot, vivaldi

Simplest version of an extension to capture a screenshot as follows:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Screenshot",
  "version": "20200507.1",
  "permissions":[
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById("capture").addEventListener('click', event => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(dataURI => {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: dataURI});
    });
    window.close();
});
```

Loaded as an unpacked extension into Vivaldi browser it works without complaint. Opens a tab with a screenshot of whichever tab is active. However, the same extension loaded into Chrome does absolutely nothing and yet throws no errors. What's missing here? The only difference I can find between this code and their [sample code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:screenshot) is that this is a popup rather than a background script.

Comment: Try moving window.close() inside the callback of captureVisibleTab.

Comment: WOW. Asynchronous miss. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[captureVisibleTab() returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab#return_value). As such window.close() potentially closes the window before the Promise has returned as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61684153/capturevisibletab-fails-on-chrome-yet-succeeds-in-vivaldi/73522426#comment109109889_61684153) by [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom). Including revised code for manifest version 3 as manifest version 2 will be phased out in 2023.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Screenshot",
    "version": "20220828.1",
    "permissions":[
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById("capture").addEventListener('click', event => 
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab().then(dataURI => 
        chrome.tabs.create({url: dataURI}).then(() => 
            window.close()
        )
    )
);
```